# JSoup vs OWSAP AntiSamy for JSON Sanitization

Tags: jsoup, xss, owasp, html-sanitizing

I am looking for a Library to perform JSON Santization and came across JSoup and OWSAP AntiSamy. Looks like AntiSamy does only HTML Sanitization and there is a separate project for JSON Santization. Also JSoup doesn't seem to be mentioning about JSON Sanitization.

Does [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer) and OWSAP AntiSamy perform JSON Sanitization ?

Comment: i am voting to close this question as it is too broad

Comment: @HashMap I've updated the question to be specific. My question was to find out the JSON Sanitization capability, if it was present in 2 libraries. Hope the question can now stay open.

Comment: Jsoup cannot do _anything_ related to JSON as far as i'm aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OWASP has a [JSON sanitizer project](https://github.com/OWASP/json-sanitizer), separate from AntiSamy, that converts JSON-like content to syntactically correct and embeddable JSON.

> The output is well-formed JSON as defined by RFC 4627. The output satisfies three additional properties:
>
> - The output will not contain the substring (case-insensitively) "`</script`" so can be embedded inside an HTML script element without further encoding.
> - The output will not contain the substring "`]]>`" so can be embedded inside an XML CDATA section without further encoding.
> - The output is a valid Javascript expression, so can be parsed by Javascript's `eval` builtin (after being wrapped in parentheses) or by `JSON.parse`. Specifically, the output will not contain any string literals with embedded JS newlines (U+2028 Paragraph separator or U+2029 Line separator).
> - The output contains only valid Unicode scalar values (no isolated UTF-16 surrogates) that are allowed in XML unescaped.